# How to fix windows 10 appx (uwp) after upgrading windows 10 build in 3 steps

Tags: build, uwp, crash, windows-10, appx

Well, when someone using an iso file to upgrade windows 10 and/or to change windows 10 edition, windows 10 appx (UWP) crashing.

This is 'quickly' fix for the problem:

1. Open `CMD` as administrator.
2. Type `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
3. Paste at once the commands you can found here: 
   https://paste.laravel.io/7b64f89b-d45d-43e6-b374-666694b5f573/raw

This may take some time ..
After it finished, do restart and thats it ! Enjoy.

Comment: don't ask/answer questions in the question. You can add your own answer with all steps you did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is **quickly** fix for the problem:

1. Open `CMD` as administrator.
2. Type `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
3. Paste at once the commands you can found [here](https://hastebin.com/raw/upisecedeq).

This may take some time .. After it finished, do restart and thats it ! Enjoy.